# mandlebrot fractal error in the plotted function

Tags: c#, fractals, mandelbrot

Hello guys i am trying plotting the mandlebrot fractal but the result is very far from it, can you help me to find the why?

Here is the code:

```
void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = pbx.CreateGraphics();
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black);

    double xmin = -2.0;
    double ymin = -1.2;
    double xmax = 0;
    double ymax = 0;
    double x = xmin, y = ymin;
    int MAX = 1000;

    double stepY = Math.Abs(ymin - ymax)/(pbx.Height);
    double stepX = Math.Abs(xmin - xmax)/(pbx.Width);

    for(int i = 0; i < pbx.Width; i++)
    {
        y = ymin;
        for(int j = 0; j < pbx.Height; j++)
        {
            double rez = x;
            double imz = y;
            int iter = 0;

            while(rez * rez + imz * imz <= 4 && iter < MAX)
            {
                rez = rez * rez - imz * imz + x;
                imz = 2 * rez * imz + y;
                iter++;
            }
            if(iter == MAX)
            {
                p.Color = Color.Black;
                g.DrawRectangle(p, i, j, 1, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                p.Color = Color.White;
                g.DrawRectangle(p, i, j, 1, 1);
            }
            y += stepY;
        }
        x += stepX;
    }
}
```

please help me my mind is getting crushed thinking how to get the beautiful mandlebrot set...
and sorry if i committed some mistakes but English is not my speaked language!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some irregularities elsewhere. The range you're plotting isn't the entire set, and I would calculate `x` and `y` directly for each pixel, rather than using increments (so as to avoid rounding error accumulating).

But it looks to me as though your main error is in the iterative computation. You are modifying the `rez` variable before you use it in the computation of the new `imz` value. Your loop should look more like this:

```
while(rez * rez + imz * imz <= 4 && iter < MAX)
{
    double rT = rez * rez - imz * imz + x;

    imz = 2 * rez * imz + y;
    rez = rT;
    iter++;
 }
```

Comment: For each generation, I would prepare arrays of x and y coordinates in the Mset, indexed by the screen rectangle pixel coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to Peters answer, you should use a color palette instead of drawing just black and white pixels.

Create a array of colors, like this: (very simple example)

```
Color[] colors = new Colors[768];
for (int i=0; i<256; i++) {
    colors[i    ]=Color.FromArgb(    i,     0, 0);
    colors[i+256]=Color.FromArgb(255-i,     i, 0);
    colors[i+512]=Color.FromArgb(0    , 255-i, i);
}
```

Then use the `iter` value to pull a color and draw it:

```
int index=(int)((double)iter/MAX*767);
p.Color c = colors[index];
g.DrawRectangle(p, i, j, 1, 1);
```

Replace the entire `if (iter == MAX) ... else ...` statement with this last step.

Comment: "Make It Work, Make It Right, Make It Fast". Until it cannot render properly, fancy colors are purely optional.

Comment: I tried to help. Drawing a Mandelbrot set, you **will** not see any result with only two colors. Trust me, I drawed them a lot. Also, the little code I gave to you is all you need for this - implementing this is done in one minute.

Comment: The Mandelbrot algorithm is about whether a point will go to infinity or not, and that is binary choice. Which is perfectly represented by 0 and 1, which is black&white in practice, most of the time. Anyway I wouldn't shun B&W Mandelbrot images, they look good. (https://www.google.hu/search?q=mandelbrot+black+and+white). I just wanted to point out that if he needs help creating a Mandelbrot, mixing in a coloring algorithm will probably add a new problem to the existing one.